# How to have a class constructor emit a event on creating new instances in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, eventemitter

I have a class MyClass:

```
var MyClass = function(){
  events.EventEmitter.call(this);
  //...
};
util.inherits(MyClass, EventEmitter);
```

I want it to emit a 'new' event every time a new instance of MyClass is created:

```
myClassInstance = new MyClass(); // emit a 'new' event from MyClass, not myClassInstance
```

I want to do this so that I can have an observer to do something every a new instance of MyClass is created. For example:

```
var MyClass = require('myclass');
MyClass.on('new', function(newInstance) {
  // do something with the new instance of MyClass
};
```

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

The first way would be to *not* emit from MyClass and instead make a new EventEmitter instance that would emit instead.

```
var MyClassEmitter = new events.EventEmitter();
var MyClass = function(){
  MyClassEmitter.emit('new', this);
};
```

This is the way I would do because it uses the least fanciness and isn't likely to break.

The second way, working directly with `MyClass`, you need to mix the EventEmitter behavior onto your constructor.

```
var MyClass = function(){
  MyClass.emit('new', this);
};

// Mix functions directly onto function.
Object.keys(events.EventEmitter.prototype).forEach(function(prop){
  MyClass[prop] = events.EventEmitter.prototype[prop];
});
// Trigger constructor in MyClass context.
events.EventEmitter.call(MyClass);
```

Comment: Reading the Mongoose source code, I found this in their model.js:  for (var i in EventEmitter.prototype)
  Model[i] = EventEmitter.prototype[i]; Is this doing the same thing as in your second approach?

Comment: Pretty much, yep! `Object.keys...` is the same as `for(var i in EventEmitter.prototype) if (EventEmitter.prototype.hasOwnProperty(i)) Model[i] = EventEmitter.prototype[i];`. The for loop without hasOwnProperty might be better actually, but either will work I'd expect.